# Stored procedure duplicated ? in DB2

Tags: database, db2, procedure, duplicate-detection

I've created a stored procedure in db2, and I've modified it a couple of times, but in my db manager (Dbbeaver) and RazorSQL the same stored procedure appears two times. How can I determine what the last version is?

Comment: The information schema tables probably have creation/modification timestamps.  Generally, you're only supposed to be able to have one of a procedure, though (ie, if you used `ALTER`, as `CREATE` should fail for a duplicate object).  If you're _testing_ multiple versions, you generally don't care about creation order, just which is `A` and which is `B` (...if this is the case, usually you name them `Old` and `New` or something similar).  What do you want this information for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On zOS DB2 the following will show the alter timestamp:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    alteredts  
FROM 
    SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES 
WHERE 
    NAME = 'myproc'
AND SCHEMA = 'myschema'
```

You'll need to have read rights to the SYSIBM tables. Also, if two SPs have the same name, it might be because they have overloaded parameters.